# How can I add a new line in MathView in Android

Tags: android, math, webview, android-webview, mathjax

I have googled but unable to find a proper solution.

MathView works fine but when I add '\' to add a new line it escapes the '\' character.
I have tried adding '\\' and '\~'. But they didn't work.

MathView: https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Comment: Maybe try `\newline`? That appears to be how to write a newline in TeX.

Comment: I added '\\\\' and it worked.

Comment: For a new line in MathView but outside of Mathjax syntax I have to add <br/> tag.

Answer (score 1):

nice try but use that inside

```
\begin{multline} first line \\ second line\end{multline}
```

here i have used $$ so its double backslash and four backslash four changing lines

```
$$\\color{black}{\\small\\begin{multline}\\text{first line} \\\\ here's my second line\\end{multline}}$$
```

Hope this helps you :)